# Unable to build caliburn.micro project in TFS 2013 build server

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

We have a solution which has Wpf project that references **caliburn.micro version 3.2.0**. The solution builds fine locally with **Visual Studio 2015**. But the build server (TFS 2013 with MSBuild 14.0) is throwing exception that it cannot find the assembly.

> AppBootstrapper.cs (4): The type or namespace name 'Caliburn' could
> not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
>
> ViewModels\EmcInventoryViewModel.cs (39): The type or namespace name
> 'IEventAggregator' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

Checked the build log file and got the following warning,

> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1820):
> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
> "Caliburn.Micro, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
> make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
> by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Tried different options like,

1. Updated to the latest version of Caliburn.Micro
2. Set the MsBuild Argument with /tv:14.0

No luck.

Comment: Have you restored the NuGet packages before building? Can you build the project locally with msbuild command line?

Comment: Yes. By default, it downloads all the nuget packages before building. And yes, tried building the Solution locally with MSBUILD and it builds fine. Funny part is, I event tried building the solution with MSBUILD inside the build server which it is working....

Comment: what about creating a new build definition? and try with another agent. Also try to clean the caches, then check it again.

Comment: Sure. Will try it...

Comment: Any update? Have you resolved that?